# how to fix "No input devices available" problem in Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-18.04, microphone

No microphone is available in my Lubuntu installation since an upgrade that happened around a month ago. On the 'Input devices' tab of my Sound settings, it says that 'No input devices available', so I can't even unmute or change the volume.

So far I have checked the codec with this command:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

The result:

```
Codec: Intel Haswell HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC290
```

I have read somewhere that I should update the alsa-base.conf file, but I haven't found such a file at the place where it was supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

I have been chasing this same problem on my Lenovo laptop running Ubuntu 18.04. My exact steps were:

- open Sound Settings
- choose the Hardware tab
- click on the Profile pulldown
- choose Analog Stereo Duplex

(Somehow my hardware profile had been set to Analog Stereo Output, which made the speakers work but not the microphone.)

My clue that the hardware still worked was to boot into Windows and test it there. I probably set the wrong profile when I was debugging a speaker volume problem with Zoom a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to open Sound Settings from the panel, then find the Configuration tab (on the right end). Then find a profile that has Analog stereo input in it. Going back on the input tab, you can verify if the settings connected to the audio input have appeared.